# Error when delete row from Jtable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, listselectionlistener

My Jtable have a listSelectionListener :

```
jTable1.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {

        @Override
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
            System.out.println(jTable1.getValueAt(jTable1.getSelectedRow(), 0));
        }
    });
```

i create a button to delete all rows of Jtable with event:

```
for (int i =jTable1.getModel().getRowCount()-1; i >=0 ; i--) {
        ((DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel()).removeRow(i);
    }
```

If i press the button without choosing any row ,there is no error but when i choose a row then press the button i get this error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
```

This don't happen when table don't have ListSelectionListener.
Where do i wrong?

Thanks in advance for help with this.

Comment: May be your JTable dost not have the data in i position.

Comment: System.out.println(jTable1.getValueAt(jTable1.getSelectedRow(), 0)); - jTable1.getSelectedRow() will return -1 if no row is selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This don't happen when table don't have ListSelectionListener

So I'm guessing that your code to remove all the rows in the table executes. As the rows are removed the row selection must change since there are no longer any rows to select.

```
System.out.println(jTable1.getValueAt(jTable1.getSelectedRow(), 0));
```

Then the above statement is executed and the getSelectedRow() method return -1 which causes the Exception. Try:

```
int selectedRow = jTable1.getSelectedRow();
System.out.println("Selected Row: " + selectedRow;

if (selectedRow != -1)
    System.out.println(jTable1.getValueAt(selectedRow, 0));
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try with this?

```
DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
dtm.setRowCount(0);
```

Comment: I don't understand your idea?

Comment: This will tell the model to have 0 rows of data The model will fire the appropriate data change events to the table which will rebuild itself.

Comment: (1+) for an easier way to remove all rows from the TableModel, although I don't think it will fix the Exception.